# + spin Photons inside a right hand circularly polarized field with -spin photons outside of that field…”dark matter/energy”

Tags: electromagnetism, photons, polarization, dark-matter, dark-energy

As I understand it, If I am inside of a rh, circularly polarized EM field, there are only +spin photons inside the field: no -spin photons are admitted inside. The field inside serves to “filter” out -spin photons.

With earth and the solar system inside an EM field, is it reasonable, that it would be at least “difficult” to “see/detect” -spin photons? Trying to observe -spin photons from inside a field that prevents their entry seems like trying to observe “dark” photons. Question: might polarized field explain why dark matter/energy is “dark” to us?

Here is added explanation for my question:
In a right-handed polarized field (for example) only + spin photons can enter the field. - spins are not allowed in according to a Blanci’s response:
“For light travelling in some direction a photon can have spin either clockwise (+1) or anti clockwise (-1) around a ray in said direction. After passing a circular polarization filter any photon will have such defined spin. Any photon which didn’t pass had the other spin. In general a photon could be in a mixture of the two possible states. An equal mixture will give linear polarization (the transverse E field direction depending on the phase relation between the 2 circular states). An uneven mixture can give an elliptical polarised wave. A mixed photon will have a certain probability to be either one or the other and therefore may or may not pass a circular Polaroid with said probabilities. Note a spin +1 photon on passing a linear Polaroid will only pass with 50 % probability. And the emerging photon now has mixed spin +1 and also spin -1 with well defined phase relation.”
Blanci’s response was related to this question: [Can a single photon have circular polarization?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/581117/can-a-single-photon-have-circular-polarization)

So, it seems IF our solar system has such a field, the we might not be able to “see” that which does not enter the local system…

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Maxwell's Eq solution allow superposition, so a field can not filter another field.